# Do "package" and "application/software/program" mean the same thing?

Tags: package-management, filesystem, application-development, debian

Are these words used interchangeably in Linux?

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *Note: This answer is restricted to Ubuntu/Debian.*

In general, **no**, they do not mean the same. A "package" is like an installer; it's a DEB file, much like MSI files in Windows.

Unless the application is relatively small, it will usually be assembled from multiple packages, with each package containing one (sometimes more) components of the program. These components can be binaries (executables), libraries, help files (man pages) and even source code.

Conversely, some packages will install multiple small programs (binaries), and others will "collect" multiple related programs under one umbrella for ease of installation *(meta-packages)*, but these are the exception rather than the rule.

In short: since most programs are made up from more than one package, they are not the same. :-)

Comment: You may want to expand this to explain how the reverse is true as well; a single package often provides multiple programs (e.g., `coreutils`) ...or no programs (documentation packages) ...or no files at all (metapackages).

Answer (score 2):

**Software** is a collection of **Programs**.

When that Software is used for performing a particular task , we say its an **Application**.

Now relating these terms for Linux- Ubuntu specifications.

Package is a specific piece of **software** which the system can **install** and **uninstall**.

> Restricting to Ubuntu/Debian.

Packages are basically of two types :  **Binary** packages and **Source** packages .

Since they require more developer friendly knowledge due to compilation and dependency technicalities , **.deb**  was developed to provide simple installation and un-installation functions compared to Window MSI or .exe formats.

(**.deb**)ian package,is used by Debian and Ubuntu.

**dpkg** (lower level) and **apt**(higher level) forms its Package Management system (PMS) used to install them.

**.deb** package contains meta-information such as a package description, version, and dependencies which allows PMS , to perform an automatic upgrade to a newer version, to check that all dependencies of a package are fulfilled and/or to fulfill them automatically.

For example : sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop.

Where Ubuntu-desktop is a **meta-package** use to install the basic desktop applications required by the default desktop using **apt** PMS .

*source : for [.deb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29),[PMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_%28package_management_system%29), [APT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool), [dpkg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg).*

Answer (score 1):

In the perspective of Ubuntu and Debian.

**No**, they are not the same thing. ***Package*** usually refers to the individual components of a full featured software. Where *Software/Application/Program* usually refers to  a full featured software which can be used standalone.

**Let's take an example:**
Then default file browser in Ubuntu *(unity)* is Nautilus. We usually refer to this as "Software" or "Application", since they can be used for a specific needs i.e *browsing files*.

But this Nautilus **Application** or **Software** depends on various small components, which usually do not provide a full feature individually, but they can be used together to build up a **Software**, which can provide full feature (*browsing files/folder*) individually.

you can see what packages `nautilus` depends on, by running this command in a terminal :

```
apt-cache depends nautilus
```

Hope this will help